# htaccess variable variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've made an php script that builds an image and I want to use htaccess for a nice url

The script builds an image depending on some variables:

for example:

```
All options given
php url:  image.php?width=300&height=400&color=red&var1=something&var2=somethingelse
nice url: image-w300-h400-cred-v1something-v2something.png

Few options given
php url:  image.php?var1=something&color=black
nice url: image-v1something-cblack.png
```

I know how to build a rewriteRule for every combination but isn't there a way to automate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always put your params in the same order, you can use this kind of rule :

```
RewriteRule 
    ^image(-w[0-9]+)?(-h[0-9]+)?(-c[a-z]+)?(-v1[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?(-v2[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?\.png$ 
    image.php?width=$1&height=$2&color=$3&var1=$4&var2=$5 [L]
```

EDIT :

```
RewriteRule 
    ^image(-w([0-9]+))?(-h([0-9]+))?(-c([a-z]+))?(-v1([A-Za-z0-9-]+))?(-v2([A-Za-z0-9-]+))?\.png$ 
    image.php?width=$2&height=$4&color=$6&var1=$8&var2=$10 [L]
```

EDIT 2 to prevent $10 problem :

```
RewriteRule 
    ^image(?:-w([0-9]+))?(?:-h([0-9]+))?(?:-c([a-z]+))?(?:-v1([A-Za-z0-9-]+))?(?:-v2([A-Za-z0-9-]+))?\.png$ 
    image.php?width=$1&height=$2&color=$3&var1=$4&var2=$5 [L]
```

Comment: This looks like what i'm searching for but the variables contain the prefixes for example width=-w200, it should be width=200

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll have to supply the arguments in the exact order or it won't match. That's not necessarily hard, but query parameters should not depend on a particular order. Also, this is pretty hard to maintain if you keep adding/changing parameters.

Comment: @deceze I agree, that's a constraint, but for SEO needs, you should never have two differents urls for the same page, then use ordered params seems to be a good practice.

Comment: $10 does not work because $10 will be $1 and 0 for example $1 = black then $10 becomes black0, i will edit your post for the solution

Answer (score 4):

Probably the simplest solution:

```
RewriteRule ^image-(.+)\.png$ image.php?params=$1
```

Then parse `$_GET['params']` in PHP.

Comment: then it's all in one parameter, what is the best way to split them up again?

Comment: `explode('-', $_GET['params'])`, then parse each individual parameter according to whatever rules you think up.

Comment: I'd think that *is* the easiest, or at least the most maintainable, solution.